Why array fails on assertion using g_array_append_vals?
Trying to create a function to check available Vulkan extensions, however my executable runs and closes within a second with an error in terminal that I've barely managed to copy. It's a CMake project. The problem is in the function.
Function:
GArray* glfwExtensions, *requiredExtensions;
uint_fast32t glfwExtensionCount;
bool enableValidationLayers = true;

int __fastcall getRequiredExtensions() {
    glfwExtensions = g_array_new_take((char**)glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount), glfwExtensionCount, false, __SIZEOF_POINTER__);
    g_array_append_vals(requiredExtensions, (const char**)(glfwExtensions->data), glfwExtensionCount);
    g_array_append_vals(requiredExtensions, (const char*[]){VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME}, 1);

    if (enableValidationLayers)
        g_array_append_vals(requiredExtensions, (const char*[]){VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME}, 1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Output in terminal:
(proces:8144): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:31:15.244: g_array_append_vals: assertion 'array' failed

(proces:8144): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:31:15.260: g_array_append_vals: assertion 'array' failed

(proces:8144): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:31:15.261: g_array_append_vals: assertion 'array' failed

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.31)

set (CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set (CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED on)

set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER "D:/msys2/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe")
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "D:/msys2/ucrt64/bin/g++.exe")
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "D:/my_proj/")
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/debug")

find_package (PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules (GLIB REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET glib-2.0)
pkg_check_modules (GLFW REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET glfw3)
pkg_check_modules (VULKAN REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET vulkan)
pkg_check_modules (CGLM REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET cglm)

option (CGLM_SHARED "Shared build" ON)
option (CGLM_STATIC "Static build" OFF)
option (CGLM_USE_C99 "" OFF)
option (CGLM_USE_TEST "Enable Tests" OFF)

project (render C)
add_executable (render D:/my_proj/render.c)

# render
target_link_options(render PRIVATE
    "-m64"
    # "-mwindows"
)

target_include_directories (render PRIVATE
    ${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${CGLM_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_compile_definitions (render PRIVATE
    ${GLIB_CFLAGS_OTHER}
    ${GLFW_CFLAGS_OTHER}
    ${VULKAN_CFLAGS_OTHER}
    ${CGLM_CFLAGS_OTHER})

target_link_directories (render PRIVATE
    ${GLIB_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${GLFW_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${VULKAN_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${CGLM_LIBRARY_DIRS})

target_link_libraries (render PRIVATE
    ${GLIB_LIBRARIES}
    ${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
    ${VULKAN_LIBRARIES}
    ${CGLM_LIBRARIES})

I tried to change the pointers from (const char*[]) to (char**), but the result is the same. I've re-read the GLib API, but there's no explanation for that whatsoever. As I've seen in other similar post with g_ptr_array_add(), that shows my GArray pointer is NULL, but I have no clue what may happen during a simple allocation with g_array_new_take().
UPD:
I forgot to initialize requiredExtensions array facepalm. Also I rewrited the function from GArray to GPtrArray by the advice of @TingPing. Now the function looks like this:
GPtrArray *glfwExtensions, *requiredExtensions;
uint_fast32t glfwExtensionCount;
bool enableValidationLayers = true;

int __fastcall getRequiredExtensions() {
    {
        const char** glfwExtTemp = (const char**)glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);
        glfwExtensions = g_ptr_array_new_take((gpointer*)glfwExtTemp, glfwExtensionCount, NULL);
        requiredExtensions = g_ptr_array_copy(glfwExtensions, NULL, NULL);
    }
    // g_ptr_array_add(requiredExtensions, VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME); <-- THIS WORKS, WHY?!

    g_ptr_array_extend_and_steal(requiredExtensions, g_ptr_array_new_take((gpointer*)(char*[]){
        VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME,
    }, 1, NULL));

    if (enableValidationLayers)
        g_ptr_array_extend_and_steal(requiredExtensions, g_ptr_array_new_take((gpointer*)(char*[]){
            VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME,
        }, 1, NULL));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

But now I have problem with the g_ptr_array_extend_and_steal calls. When I eject them from code it works, otherwise the program crashes. I can't use validation layers due to that (No debug extension correspondingly). Moreover, when I append one single element with g_ptr_array_add it works! What is the problem of appending multiple pointers with g_ptr_array_extend_and_steal?

Can you update the code to your latest failing version with the requiredExtensions initialization?

Sure thing, updated the code

GPtrArray is definitely what you want. new_take on unowned memory is also strange.

Tried to re-write the function with GPtrArray. Same thing (updated again). But now for some reason when I use g_ptr_array_add it works, however using g_ptr_array_extend_and_steal causes the same problem as before

Documentation for g_ptr_array_new_take clearly tells that the first argument should be dynamically allocated, because later it will be passed to g_free. If you want to create an array from non-allocated C array, use g_ptr_array_new_from_array instead.

When edit a question on Stack Overflow (e.g. given one), note that we don't want "UPDATE", "EDIT" or similar parts. We expect a question post (and a question title) to describe the current problem only. Parts related to the older problems should be removed from the post. For anyone who is curious about previous state of the question, there is a link named "edited ..." below the post.

Oh, thanks, it indeed worked! I replaced all g_ptr_array_new_takes by g_ptr_array_new_from_arrays. Just asking in advance, when my previous problem is solved, but a new question appeared, do I need to create another post separately or I may just edit the title and the body of the following one?

The easy rule: a new problem requires new question. In that case, if you feel that your current question has a little value for future visitors, then you may delete it. But be sure to not delete many questions, otherwise you will be in risk of being question-banned. Unless your question has an answer, you may change the question to the new state, about new problem. Note, that many of us don't like such "chameleon" questions, so do not abuse such question changes. See also that question on meta.

Alright, appreciate your help! :)
